# convert binaryTree to LinkedList with only Leaf Nodes

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list, binary-tree

This is the question.

Given a binary tree we need to make linked list out of the leaf nodes. Constraints were that it was supposed to be done using O(1) extra space. Also we can use node->right pointer to connect the linked list.

Given the tree below.

```
      10

 5           12
     7   11      15
```

result should be:

```
           10

     5           12
 L ->   7 -> 11  ->   15
```

Note L is a new Pointer, that references the leafNodes, each leafNodes have right pointers to them.

Here is what I tried:

```
public class TreeManipulationMethods {

    private static IntTreeNode linkedlist=null;
    private static IntTreeNode prev=null;
    private static int preIndex=0;
    private static Node headNode;



   public static void main(String[] args){

      IntTreeNode tree1=new IntTreeNode(10);
        tree1.left=new IntTreeNode(5);
        tree1.left.right=new IntTreeNode(7);
        tree1.right=new IntTreeNode(12);
        tree1.right.left=new IntTreeNode(11);
        tree1.right.right=new IntTreeNode(15);

       convertToLinkedListWithOnlyLeafNodes(tree1);
        linkedlist.printRight();
    }

    public static void convertToLinkedListWithOnlyLeafNodes(IntTreeNode root){

        if (root==null)
            return;

        convertToLinkedListWithOnlyLeafNodes(root.left);
        if (isLeaf(root)){
             if (linkedlist==null)
                 linkedlist=root;
             else 
                 prev.right=root;
             prev=root;
        }
        convertToLinkedListWithOnlyLeafNodes(root.right);
    }

  private static boolean isLeaf(IntTreeNode root){
        return root!=null || (root.left==null && root.right==null);
    }
}

class IntTreeNode {

    int val;
    IntTreeNode right;
    IntTreeNode left;

    public IntTreeNode(int val){
        this.val=val;
    }

    public void printRight(){
        String toRet="[ ";
        IntTreeNode current = this;
        while(current!=null){
            toRet+=current.val + " -> ";
            current=current.right;
        }
        toRet+="NULL ]";
        System.out.println(toRet);
    }
}
```

The output is:
`[ 5 -> 7 -> 10 -> 11 -> 12 -> 15 -> NULL ]`

which obviously is not correct.

The expected output will be
`[7->11->15]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you need to add only the leaf nodes, i.e below is the conditions
 To be leaf node - it shouldnt have left & right nodes  i.e root.left & root.right should be null

i guess you need to make a && condition, like below

```
 root!=null && (root.left==null && root.right==null)
```

Note : this is not tested.